# How to arrange picklist values to multiple columns in pageblocktable

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a pageblocktable in which i am displaying statuses`(Open,InProcess,Closed)`.but in object the `Status__c` field is picklist(stores 12 statuses like stat1,stat2,stat3 comes in `Open` Status sta4,stat5....stat10 comes under `InProces`s Status,and stat11,stat12 in `Closed` status).

The table should looks like

```
Category TotalRecords Open InProcess Closed
  cat1       8          2      1        5
  cat2       5          3      2        0
```

I am getting data group by Category__c field and Counting the Records which gives correct data,but how can i arrange the values in  Status__c field to (Open,InProcess,Closed).

class:

```
 public List<Data> dt{get;set;}
 public class Data
 {
     public AggregateResult ar {get; set;}
     public String Status{get { return (string)ar.get('status'); }}
     public decimal Open { get;set;}
     public decimal InProcess { get;set;}
     public decimal Closed{ get;set;}
  }
```

I am getting data and assigning to the list `dt`. based on the property `status` i need to assign values to Open,InProcess,Closed.

I tried iterating through the list `dt`.and checking `Status` value and assign to the (Open,InProcess,Closed) which is not giving the correct result.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class:

```
Set<String> openStatusSet = new Set<String>{'status1', 'status2', ... };
Set<String> inProcessStatusSet = new Set<String>{'status4', 'status5', ... };
Set<String> closedStatusSet = new Set<String>{'status11', 'status12', ... };

public List<Data> getDataList(){
    Map<String, Data> dataMap = new Map<String, Data>();  // dataMap: category ---> Data
    for(AggregateResult at :[SELECT count(Id) cnt, Category__c, Status__c FROM YourObject__c Group By Category__c, Status__c]{
        String category = (String)ar.get('Category__c');
        Data tempData = dataMap.get(category);
        if(tempData == null)
            tempData = new Data(category); // TODO: Create Constructor + initialize counts
        String status = (String)ar.get('Status__c');
        Decimal recordCount = (Decimal)ar.get('cnt');
        if(openStatusSet.contains(status))
            tempData.open += recordCount;
        if(inProcessStatusSet.contains(status))
            tempData.inProcess += recordCount;
        if(closedStatusSet.contains(status))
            tempData.closed += recordCount;

        dataMap.put(category,  tempData);
    }
    return dataMap.values();
}
```

Then render the `pageBlockTable` as usual

```
<apex: pageBlockTable value="{!DataList}" var="data">
    <apex:column columnName="Category" value="{!data.category}"/>
    <apex:column columnName="Open" value="{!data.open}"/>
    <apex:column columnName="In Process" value="{!data.inProcess}"/>
    <apex:column columnName="Closed" value="{!data.closed}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: And i initialize Open,InProcess,Closed properties to 0 in Constructor..

Comment: Thanks @amatorVitae.The concept works as expected but the TotalRecord count showing incorrectly.

Comment: Add a `tempData.total += recordCount` before it puts the `data` into the map